# Python: creating undirected weighted graph from a co-occurrence matrix

Tags: python, matrix, graph, networkx, defaultdict

I am using Python 2.7 to create a project that would use Twitter data and analyze it. The main concept is to collect tweets and get the most common hashtags used in that collection of tweets and then I need to create a graph where hashtags would be nodes. If those hashtags would happen to appear in the same tweet that would be an edge in the graph and weight of that edge would be the co-occurrence number. So I am trying to create a dictionary of dictionaries using `defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))` and create a graph using `networkx.from_dict_of_dicts`

My code for creating the co-occurrence matrix is

```
def coocurrence (common_entities):


com = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

# Build co-occurrence matrix
for i in range(len(common_entities)-1):            
    for j in range(i+1, len(common_entities)):
        w1, w2 = sorted([common_entities[i], common_entities[j]])                
        if w1 != w2:
            com[w1][w2] += 1


return com
```

But in order to use `networkx.from_dict_of_dicts` I need it to be in this format: `com= {0: {1:{'weight':1}}}`

Do you have any ideas how I can solve this? Or a different way of creating a graph like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would sort the entities first, so you're not continually running sort inside the loop.  Then I would use itertools.combinations to get the combinations.  The straightforward translation of what you need with those changes is this:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict


def coocurrence (common_entities):

    com = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda: {'weight':0}))

    # Build co-occurrence matrix
    for w1, w2 in combinations(sorted(common_entities), 2):
        if w1 != w2:
            com[w1][w2]['weight'] += 1

    return com

print coocurrence('abcaqwvv')
```

It may be more efficient (less indexing and fewer objects created) to build something else first and then generate your final answer in a second loop.  The second loop won't run for as many cycles as the first because all the counts have already been calculated.  Also, since the second loop isn't running for as many cycles, it may be that deferring the `if statement` to the second loop could save more time.  As usual, run timeit on multiple variations if you care, but here is one possible example of the two loop solution:

```
def coocurrence (common_entities):

    com = defaultdict(int)

    # Build co-occurrence matrix
    for w1, w2 in combinations(sorted(common_entities), 2):
        com[w1, w2] += 1

    result = defaultdict(dict)
    for (w1, w2), count in com.items():
        if w1 != w2:
            result[w1][w2] = {'weight': count}
    return result

print coocurrence('abcaqwvv')
```

Comment: While working further on my project I created a function that creates a graph from a matrix I got using my code 
`def create_graph(cooccurrence_matrix):
    
    g = nx.Graph()
        for e,co in cooccurrence_matrix.iteritems():
            if co >= 3:
                g.add_edge(e[0], e[1], weight=co)

    return g`

But when I run it says `TypeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object is not callable` and I can't figure out why. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @banana -- Nothing in that code stands out to me as being problematic, but I am not an nx expert.  Usually, the entire diagnostic traceback is useful, and that doesn't fit very well in a comment, so if you can create an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's probably worth posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the working code and best

```
def coocurrence(*inputs):
com = defaultdict(int)

for named_entities in inputs:
    # Build co-occurrence matrix
    for w1, w2 in combinations(sorted(named_entities), 2):
        com[w1, w2] += 1
        com[w2, w1] += 1  #Including both directions

result = defaultdict(dict)
for (w1, w2), count in com.items():
    if w1 != w2:
        result[w1][w2] = {'weight': count}
return result
```

Comment: Could you explain as to why this code is the best

Comment: well, I used and run it and it's working accurately as required and mentioned in the code.